# How to autofit row using a variable

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use vba in excel to autofit a row that is beforehand stored in a variable, but can't get it to work. Anybody have any ideas?

```
Sub test1()

Dim intYellowRow As Integer
intYellowRow = 18

With Rows(intYellowRow & ":" & intYellowRow).EntireRow
    .AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close:

```
Sub test1()
  Dim intYellowRow As Integer 
    intYellowRow = 18
    Rows(intYellowRow).EntireRow.AutoFit 
End Sub
```